# Proper location for state in ReactJS with three layers of components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to wrap my head around having state in ReactJS. It seems to me that I'm forced to push the state of my editor components up several levels that just don't make sense to me. I think I'm misunderstanding the ReactJS style in this situation.

I've tried to simplify this as much as possible. My basic component setup is this:

ViewStore -> StoreDetailsTab -> ZoneEditor

The ViewStore is responsible for the Store object as state, that much is clear, since an entire array of different views render based on that store object. Therefore, my ZoneEditor component calls an updateZone method on StoreDetailsTab, which in turn calls an updateStore method on the ViewStore component.

The problem is, my ZoneEditor has other state that seems to rightly belong internal to its control. This includes mouse positions and state related to the selecting / dragging & dropping / tooling on this widget.

When the ZoneEditor calls updateZone (which becomes updateStore), both the StoreDetails and ZoneEditor objects appear to get recreated due to the setState call made by the ViewStore component. This destroys their internal state, including the internal state of ZoneEditor.

My question is, am I doing something wrong? Or is the ReactJS style to push the ZoneEditors internal state all the way up through the component hierarchy to the ViewStore component?

```
class ViewStore extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            store: {},
            isUpdatingStore: false,
            showUpdateFailure: false,
            showUpdateSuccess: false
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: '/store/' + this.props.match.params.storeId,
        }).then((response) =>
        {
            this.setState({store: response.data})
        });
    }


    updateStore(newStore)
    {
        this.setState({
            store: newStore,
            isUpdatingStore: true
        });

        return axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/store/' + this.props.match.params.storeId,
            data: newStore
        }).then(() =>
        {
            this.setState({
                isUpdatingStore: false,
                showUpdateSuccess: true
            });

            setTimeout(() => this.setState({showUpdateSuccess: false}), 5000);
        }, () =>
        {
            this.setState({
                isUpdatingStore: false,
                showUpdateFailure: true
            });

            setTimeout(() => this.setState({showUpdateFailure: false}), 5000);
        });
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <ContentWrapper class="ViewStore">
                <div className="content-heading">
                    Store
                    <small>Please enter the details</small>
                </div>
                <Row>
                    <Col sm={ 12 }>
                        <StoreDetailsTab {...(_.extend({}, this.props, this.state, {updateStore: this.updateStore.bind(this)}))} />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </ContentWrapper>
        );
    }
}


class StoreDetailsTab extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {isUploading: false, storeLayoutCacheBreaker: ""};
    }

    updateZones(zones)
    {
        const store = this.props.store;
        store.zones = zones;
        this.props.updateStore(store);
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <br/>
                <Panel header="Store Details">
                    {
                        this.props.store ?
                            <Row>
                                <Col xs={12}>
                                    <h2>Zones</h2>

                                    <ZoneEditor
                                        src={'http://localhost:1806/store/' + this.props.match.params.storeId + "/store_layout?" + this.state.storeLayoutCacheBreaker}
                                        zones={this.props.store.zones}
                                        updateZones={this.updateZones.bind(this)}
                                    />
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
                            : null

                    }
                </Panel>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class ZoneEditor extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {};
    }

    componentDidMount() {

    }

    updateZones(zones) {
        if (this.props.updateZones) {
            this.props.updateZones(zones);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Triggered when this component is being removed from the screen
     */
    componentWillUnmount() {

    }

    onMouseDown(evt) {
        if (!this.state.isEditingZone) {
            // Start a new rectangle
            this.setState({
                isDraggingZone: true,
                isEditingZone: false,
                startX: evt.nativeEvent.offsetX,
                startY: evt.nativeEvent.offsetY,
                dragX: evt.nativeEvent.offsetX,
                dragY: evt.nativeEvent.offsetY
            }, this.updateZoneCoordinates.bind(this));
        }
        else {
            this.setState({
                isDraggingZone: false,
                isEditingZone: false
            }, this.updateZoneCoordinates.bind(this))
        }
    }

    onMouseMove(evt) {
        if (this.state.isDraggingZone && !this.state.isEditingZone) {
            // Start a new rectangle
            this.setState({
                dragX: evt.nativeEvent.offsetX,
                dragY: evt.nativeEvent.offsetY
            }, this.updateZoneCoordinates.bind(this));
        }
    }


    onMouseUp(evt) {
        if (this.state.isDraggingZone && !this.state.isEditingZone) {
            // Start a new rectangle
            this.setState({
                isDraggingZone: false,
                isEditingZone: true,
                dragX: evt.nativeEvent.offsetX,
                dragY: evt.nativeEvent.offsetY,
                editorX: evt.nativeEvent.offsetX,
                editorY: evt.nativeEvent.offsetY
            }, this.updateZoneCoordinates.bind(this));


            const zones = this.props.zones;
            zones.push(this.computeZoneCoordinates());
            this.updateZones(zones);
        }
    }


    computeZoneCoordinates() {
        const width = Math.abs(this.state.startX - this.state.dragX);
        const height = Math.abs(this.state.startY - this.state.dragY);
        const left = Math.min(this.state.startX, this.state.dragX);
        const top = Math.min(this.state.startY, this.state.dragY);

        return {left, top, width, height};
    }


    updateZoneCoordinates() {
        this.setState({zone: this.computeZoneCoordinates()});
    }


    onChangeZoneType(newType) {
        this.setState({
            zoneType: newType,
            isEditingZone: false
        })
    }


    preventEventHandler(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        const options = [
            {value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate'},
            {value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry'},
            {value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla'}
        ];

        return <div className="zone-editor">
            <div
                onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown.bind(this)}
                onMouseUp={this.onMouseUp.bind(this)}
                onMouseMove={this.onMouseMove.bind(this)}>
                <img src={this.props.src} draggable={false}/>
            </div>
            {
                this.state.isDraggingZone && this.state.zone ?
                    <div className="zone-overlay" style={{
                        "left": this.state.zone.left,
                        "top": this.state.zone.top,
                        "height": this.state.zone.height,
                        "width": this.state.zone.width
                    }}/>
                    : null
            }
            {
                this.props.zones ?
                    this.props.zones.map((zone) =>
                        zone != null ?
                            <div className="zone-overlay" style={{
                                "left": zone.left,
                                "top": zone.top,
                                "height": zone.height,
                                "width": zone.width
                            }}/>
                            : null
                    )
                    : null
            }
            {
                this.state.isEditingZone ?
                    <Popover
                        id="popover-basic"
                        placement="right"
                        positionLeft={this.state.editorX}
                        positionTop={this.state.editorY - 48}
                        title="Popover right">
                        <Select
                            options={options}
                            value={this.state.zoneType}
                            onChange={this.onChangeZoneType.bind(this)}
                        />
                    </Popover>
                    : null
            }
        </div>;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is having stateless components and letting redux control state an option? This is usually how you can share part of state over multiple components at different nesting levels.

Comment: I have never used redux, although its an option to look into. I am trying to understand the React native approach to this situation.

Comment: you might want to take a look in react context API, you could create a context specifically for that situation and would avoid the redux overhead

Comment: There may be another problem with your code. You are doing something asynchronous depending on user interaction? So if user does ABC and asynchronous reply comes in as ACB then the state will be set with result of B even though last user action was C. Not sure if it applies to you but [here](https://codepen.io/amsterdamharu/pen/KRQKLj?editors=0010) is how you could prevent this from happening (ignores results of A and B when a newer request was made like C)